# Block Toolbar from collapsing when RecyclerView is empty

Tags: android, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have CollapsingToolbarLayout which depends on scrolling of RecyclerView in Fragment in ViewPager. The problem is that ViewPager is too high and out of bounds of CoordinatorLayout, independently whether it has "match_parent" or "wrap_content" layout_height. Thus ViewPager scrolls even if RecyclerView has only few items.
And other problem is that I can not make static elements in fragments in ViewPager. I want make FAB floating over the RecyclerView, but the FAB  is located under the bottom bound of the screen until I will scroll it up.

Here some code

Main Layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:background="@android:color/white">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="122dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="56dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:background="@color/default_green"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Fragment:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"/>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/bookMark"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_shape3x"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/default_green"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:elevation="4sp"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    android:contentDescription=""/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve this proplem in such way. First of all I blocked AppBarLayout from scrolling like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32699543/3315714). 
And then I placed FAB directly to the CoordinatorLayout and lincked it's hidding to the ViewPager scrolls like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31663686/3315714).
Also I wanted an EditText floating over the one of the fragments, which are inside ViewPager. I placed it inside CoordinatorLayout and made it sliding up and down, when ViewPager scrolls.